# 'This process is not trusted! Input event monitoring will not be possible until it is added to accessibility clients.'

Tags: python, macos

I'm using pynput for an autoclicker program, which requires input monitoring (I'm on mac) but it always spits out 'This process is not trusted! Input event monitoring will not be possible until it is added to accessibility clients.'

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


delay = 0.001
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='s')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='e')


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

(not my code)

I have allowed PyCharm and the Terminal to monitor input, which solved the same problem for another user, but it didn't work for me. Are there any more files or applications which I need to give access to inout monitoring?

Comment: Presumably, you  need the Python executable to have that permission.

Comment: Is there a better way to search for a file in this case because no every time i search for a certain file, i get bombarded with any file that has anything to do with python?

Comment: What on earth does this question have to do with searching?